# Why Qt5 QtWebView just for QML Application on Android and IOS

Tags: qml, qt5, qtwebview

Qt5 QtWebView use the native webview apis to show web pages, and it's a good idea. But why does QtWebView just support QML application?

I designed my mobile apps for Android and IOS. I chose Qt5, because it took only one day to design 10 pages of my apps. I love Qt very much. But when I want webview to show a web page, there is no better solution.

Two ways I can think of are:

1. QML WebView
2. Qt call Android and IOS code.

But it will affect the user experience. So what should I do?

Why does QtWebView not support C++ code? I just add it to UI files , and code my apps very fast. I know QML is very good , but we can't ignore C++.

The offical document: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebview-index.html

*QML Types
The module provides a single QML component for displaying web content in the application: WebView.*

Comment: Qt WebView supports C ++ and QML. You should check http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebview-module.html

Comment: @eyllanesc The C++ API is only for initializing resources. You cannot create a `WebView` object in C++.